# Finding null values with .whereIn

Tags: sql, knex.js

I have a built a query with Knex as follows:

```
knex('discounts')
  .where((builder) => {
    builder
      .where('product_code', productCode)
      .where((builder1) => {
        builder1
          .andWhere('account_code', customer)
          .orWhere('account_code', null);
      });
  })
.select('*');
```

Everything works fine, but I felt like the `.where` statement is too long so tried to use the `.whereIn` function, and that's when I realized it doesn't work:

```
knex('discounts')
  .where((builder) => {
    builder
      .where('product_code', productCode)
      .whereIn('account_code', [customer, null]);
  })
.select('*');
```

I am aware that we cannot use `null` with an `IN` in raw SQL and it should be done like so:

```
WHERE 
(columnName IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') OR columnName IS NULL)
```

My question: is my initial query the only way to achieve this or is there any alternative way to use `.whereIn` with a `null` when using Knex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about the first query, the extra inline function is unnecessary. There's only really one grouping required here, if I understand your requirement correctly. So this is fine:

```
db("discounts")
  .where("product_code", productCode)
  .where(qb =>
    qb.where("account_code", customer).orWhereNull("account_code")
  )
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM "discounts"
  WHERE "product_code" = ?
  AND ("account_code" = ? OR "account_code" IS NULL)
```

You can use `.andWhere` if you want to be more explicit, but it doesn't change the generated SQL:

```
  .where("product_code", productCode)
  .andWhere(qb =>
```

By the way (if you haven't already discovered) you can review what SQL will be executed for any Knex chain by adding `.debug()` to it. This can be handy if you're refactoring, or just curious.

Answer (score 2):

More optimized I will do

```
   knex('discounts')
   .where('product_code', productCode)
   .where((builder1) => {
        builder1
          .whereIn('account_code', customer)
          .orWhereNull('account_code');
      });
  })
.then();
```

Was added inline `where` and `.orWhere('account_code', null);` was replaced with`orWhereNull`. Tips if you select `*` is not need to write `select`, default query builder is select.
Inside whereIn array values can be one/multiple variables with null values, knex not translate whereIn  to =>`whereIn or where Is NOT NULL`